# Ubuntu 20.04 Nautilus samba settings

Tags: nautilus, samba

I am trying to access samba shares on my NAS with a Ubuntu client (20.04) via Nautilus. But Nautilus will only see the Samba shares when I enable SMB1 on the server. Why is Nautilus on SMB1? I'd like to force Nautilus to a higher Samba version. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The way I read your post is: The server ( NAS ) did not have SMB1 enabled. The Ubuntu client could not get share enumeration of that Server until you enabled SMB1 on the Server.

Is that correct?

If so it is a bug.

The samba client in Ubuntu 20 can by default go from SMB2.02 all the way up to SMB3.11 so it is already capable of connecting to a server at a higher dialect.

The problem is a bug in gvfsd-smb-browse which is hard wired to scan the network at SMB1 but then gets stuck there. But this only happens when you browse the network for samba hosts. The only way around this issue is to bypass gvfsd-smb-browse:

You can do that from Nautilus by asking for the server and share explicitly in the Location bar or using Connect to Server:

```
smb://nas-hostname/share-name
```

OR

```
smb://nas-home-name.local/share-name
```

OR

```
smb://nas-ip-address/share-name
```

OR
Doing a mount.cifs mount which also goes from SMB2 to SMB3 by default but doesn't use gvfsd-smb-browse:

I would suggest creating a mount point under /media ( lets say /media/nas-share ) for reasons explained below:

Make sure cifs-utils is installed: `sudo apt install cifs-utils`

If your nas allows guest access:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //nas-ip-address/nas-share /media/nas-share cifs guest,uid=marc
```

If your nas requires credentials:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //nas-ip-address/nas-share /media/nas-share cifs username=XXXXX,password=YYYYY,uid=marc
```

It's the **uid=marc** option that replaces root as the owner of the mounted share with marc so that he has r/w access.

Once this works you can add an entry into /etc/fstab so that you can mount as required through Nautilus and not have to do a terminal mount. So in fstab it would look something like this:

```
//nas-ip-address/nas-share /media/nas-share cifs username=XXXXX,pasword=YYYYY,uid=marc,noauto,user 0 0
```

**noauto** = makes it not mount automatically at boot.

**user** = allows an ordinary user ( not sudo ) the ability to mount the share.

Since the share is mounted under /media an icon will appear on the side panel of Nautilus and when selected will mount that share per the instructions in fstab. That same icon can be used later to unmount the share.

Comment: I tried the mount.cifs solution but ran into permission problems. Connecting via Nautilus at least gave me write access (but under SMB1 which is bad). If you could post your mount command I can try that. Maybe we can solve my permission issue. The problem was that I have to run mount as sudo and then the samba share is owned by root. The Nautilus user (not root) has then no write access. I couldn't find a solution to that.

Comment: I have edit my answer to include a description of how I would mount the cifs share.

Comment: "...asking for the server and share explicitly in the Location bar..." - This can be done by pressing `Ctrl-L` while Nautilus (a.k.a. "Files") has focus.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help but on the server size, is WS-discovery activated?
On my synology server, I had to go to Control panel/ File services / Advanced to activate it (last option in the list).

Comment: @morbius1    yes. Your interpretation of my problem is spot on. 
Thanks for your detailed tips. I will check this.
The Nautilus guys don't seem to know that much. I raised a ticket and after some clarifications I provided they never came back. Maybe you can give them a pointer.(and yes ws discovery is on)